# list comprehension looping with if/else statement from 2d nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

The following snippet works and it produces exactly what I want, however I need some pointers on how to be more Pythonic with the line

```
if avail[employee, day, "Morning"].varValue==0 and    
    avail[employee, day, "Mid"].varValue==0 and 
    avail[employee, day, "Night"].varValue==0:
```

Full code

```
Shift_pattern_Master = ["Morning", "Mid", "Night"]

    for employee in Employees:
        for day in Days:
            if avail[employee, day, "Morning"].varValue==0 and    
                avail[employee, day, "Mid"].varValue==0 and 
                avail[employee, day, "Night"].varValue==0:
                    print (f"{employee} on {day} is off.")
            else:
                for shift in Shift_pattern_Master:
                    if avail[employee, day, shift].varValue==1:
                        print (f"{employee} on {day} works in {shift}.")
```

so I tried `if avail[employee, day, shift].varValue==0 for shift in Shift_pattern_Master:` to make it a generic condition and it keeps saying `for` is INVALID SYNTAX.

I think I am missing something, but I don't know what. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
if all(avail[employee, day, time].varValue==0 for time in ["Morning", "Mid", "Night"]):
```

Another option would be just to rewrap the condition:

```
if (
    avail[employee, day, "Morning"].varValue==0
    and avail[employee, day, "Mid"].varValue==0
    and avail[employee, day, "Night"].varValue==0
):
```

Comment: One minor change I'd suggest-  replace X`==0` with `not` X

Comment: Probably a good idea (then you could also do `not any(ava.....varValue for ti....)`, but not strictly equivalent.

Comment: thank you @L3viathan. it works very well.  that's what I was missing.  I am still a beginner and I definitely learn something today.